# SPFieldLookupValue and unboxing

Tags: development, conversion

I have a general question around unboxing vs parsing of the identity property on an SPFieldLookupValue.

Let's say, we have a call to a list and we get a reference to the a lookup field:

```
// call to site / web, get instance of class and iterate through records
// find column [lookup field]
SPFieldLookupValue fieldName = item["ALookupField"] as SPFieldLookupValue;
```

In the example above, I have a reference to the lookup value, whereby I can pull the Id and the Value separately instead of working with a string (ie. id#value).

Now, the LookupId property is of type object, but I know that this value will in almost all cases be an integer, so my assumption here is that I can do:

```
int id = (int)fieldName.LookupId;
```

But, obviously I need to ensure that I am working with an integer, so I should, in theory, try and parse this to the type I need:

```
bool isInt = int.TryParse(fieldName, out intField);
```

I know that this is probably more accurate, but my question is why can I not explicitly unbox the object, to it's int equivalent, when I know that it will most likely always be an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LookupId` is of type `int`. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvalue.lookupid.aspx)

Comment: And he is casting to int?

Comment: There is no need to cast as property itself returns int. He can simply use int lookupId = fieldName.LookupId

Comment: As Nadeem said, LookupId property is already int. You don't need to explicitly cast it to int !

Comment: What I meant really, was the you maybee should extend your answer to make sure OP realized what you mean by that, and how he could go along without any casting :)